# How to fix npm install and npm run dev error in Laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

How can I fix an `npm install` and a `npm run dev` error in Laravel?

> F:\new xampp\htdocs\img\hos-sps>npm install npm ERR! code
> ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT npm ERR! network
> Invalid response body while trying to fetch
> https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fhelper-plugin-utils: Socket
> timeout npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network
> connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or
> have bad network settings. npm ERR! network npm ERR! network If you
> are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy'
> config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\sammy
> waweru\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-10T17_32_47_296Z-debug-0.log
>
> F:\new xampp\htdocs\img\hos-sps>npm help config

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache and run your npm install and dev commands.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

The above will delete all data out of the cache folder. Note that this is typically unnecessary, as npm's cache is self-healing and resistant to data corruption.